# How to properly use Dagger 2 to callback from adapter to activity/fragment?

Tags: android, dagger-2

**I'm talking about the [new architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) that was presented on the last Google IO.**

Now I have the next implementation:

```
public class ThumbnailsAdapterViewModel extends ViewModel {

    MutableLiveData<ThumbnailSelected> thumbnailSelectedMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    @Inject
    public ThumbnailsAdapterViewModel() {
    }

    public LiveData<ThumbnailSelected> getSelectedThumbnail() {
        return thumbnailSelectedMutableLiveData;
    }

    public void setThumbnailSelected(ThumbnailSelected thumbnailSelected) {
        thumbnailSelectedMutableLiveData.setValue(thumbnailSelected);
    }
}
```

MyFragment:

```
@Inject
ThumbnailsAdapter thumbnailsAdapter;


// onCreateView
ThumbnailsAdapterViewModel thumbnailsAdapterViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(ThumbnailsAdapterViewModel.class);
        thumbnailsAdapterViewModel.getSelectedThumbnail().observe(this, new Observer<ThumbnailSelected>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable ThumbnailSelected thumbnailSelected) {
                if (thumbnailSelected != null) {
                    Snackbar.make(getView(), "Thumbnail #" + thumbnailSelected.getPosition() + " is selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

thumbnailsAdapter.setViewModel(thumbnailsAdapterViewModel);
```

ThumbnailsAdapter:

```
public class ThumbnailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ThumbnailsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<Thumbnail> thumbnails;
    private ThumbnailsAdapterViewModel viewModel;

    @Inject
    public ThumbnailsAdapter(List<Thumbnail> thumbnails) {
        this.thumbnails = thumbnails;
    }

    public void setViewModel(ThumbnailsAdapterViewModel viewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_thumbnail, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindData(thumbnails.get(position), position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return thumbnails.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         // ... implementation

    public void bindData(final Thumbnail thumbnail, final int position) {

            imageThumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail);

            imageThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    viewModel.setThumbnailSelected(new ThumbnailSelected(thumbnail, position));
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The main disadvantage: I'm passing `ViewModel` into `Adapter` but it would be ideal to `inject` it, but I cannot (at least I don't know how to do it properly). I guess that `ViewModel` is just created with some another scope. I tried to create it in the next class:

```
@Module
public class ActivityModuleScopeMain {

    @Provides
    List<Thumbnail> provideThumbnails() {
        List<Thumbnail> thumbnails = new ArrayList<>();
        // here the list for adapter is created
        return thumbnails;
    }
}
```

One more dagger module to present whole (I hope) picture:

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityModuleMain {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = ActivityModuleScopeMain.class)
    abstract MainFragment contributeMainFragment();
}
```

If it's not enough I'm ready to post more code.

It's working solution but I'm not satisfied.

Comment: can you look into my tutorial https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp

Comment: @Saveen sure, could you tell me where exactly should I look?